# Match table rows by REST query-like patterns?

Tags: regex, abap, opensql

I am implementing ReSTful SICF services for a customer. The SICF service has a single handler (implementing `IF_HTTP_EXTENSION~HANDLE_REQUEST`) and this calls further API handling classes. The API handling class is stored against the incoming path like this

```
DDIC Table: ZAPI_HNLDRS
    /animals/:id           | ZCL_HANDLE_ANIMALS
    /animals/:id/tiger/:id | ZCL_HANDLE_TIGER
```

When the API is called `/animals/:id/tiger/:id` looks like `/animals/4545152/tiger/1423331`.

How do I make a call to ZAPI_HNDLRS to get ZCL_HANDLE_TIGER?

Of course, this won't help,

```
select single HANDLING_CLASS from ZAPI_HNDLRS
  into <wa> where uri = '/animals/4545152/tiger/1423331'
```

I believe I have to use REGEX in some form - I amn't sure how though. How do I match patterns in an ABAP select query?

**update**

The reason I have a table to store API handlers is because I want the whole  process to be dynamic.

We could have newer urls that could be added over a period of time that could look like this.

Thanks for the answers that use SPLIT
But that's still not fully dynamic. There could be multiple new urls that could come up in the future. E.g.

```
/animals/:id/tiger/:id/claws
/animals/:id/tiger/:id/claws/:id
:id - is an unique id
```

When such cases arise, there will be new handler entries in table `ZAPI_HNDLRS`.

Hence, I would need a  generic logic to convert any incoming resource path. let's say: `/animals/1234243242423/tiger/32423443344/claws` to it's pattern that's stored `/animals/:id/tiger/:id/claws` 
So that I know the right handler to pick up from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is very difficult to do this in a single line of code.
Here is a demo for your reference:

```
DATA:
  lv_char_org    TYPE char120 VALUE '/animals/4545152/tiger/1423331',
  lv_char_target TYPE char120,
  lt_char_set    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF char120.

SPLIT lv_char_org AT '/' INTO TABLE lt_char_set.
DELETE lt_char_set INDEX 1.

LOOP AT lt_char_set INTO DATA(lv_char_set).
  IF sy-tabix MOD 2 EQ 1.
    lv_char_target = lv_char_target && '/' && lv_char_set && '/'.
  ELSE.
    lv_char_target = lv_char_target && 'id:'.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

WRITE lv_char_target.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use REGEX you are probably looking for this

`REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '/\d+/' IN lv_input WITH '/:id/'`

For Regex see SAP Help:

https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abenregex_syntax_specials.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to split the URI but in this case it seems to be over the top, because a simple [SPLIT](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapsplit.htm#!ABAP_ONE_ADD@1@) would suffice. Once you have the URI split into its different parts you can put it back together again with the ':id' strings replacing the actual ID's. If needed you could also add some checks on the ID parts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first recommend writing your HTTP handler in a separate class inheriting from `CL_REST_RESOURCE` rather than trying squeeze everything into handle_request. In that class say `ZCL_API_ANIMALS_TIGER` you'd reimplement the methods corresponding to HTTP verbs. Your SICF node should inherit from `cl_rest_http_handler`.

In the method if_rest_application~get_root_handler of your SICF node, you'd attach the handler in this kind of way

```
lo_router->attach( iv_template = '/animals/{ID}/tiger/{tigerID} '   iv_handler_class = 'ZCL_API_ANIMALS_TIGER' ).
```

From there, you could pick off the ID or tiger ID from the table coming from `mo_request->get_uri_attributes( )` when executing your request.